# Submenu not showing when scrollbar is added to dropdown menu in bootstrap 2.3.2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .scrollable-menu {
            max-height : 200px;
            overflow-y : auto;  
        }

    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Program <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu" >
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Reach</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Level1</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Level2</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Level3</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Level4</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Level5</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Level6</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Level7</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Reach For Reading</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Level1</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Level2</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Level3</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Level4</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Level5</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Level6</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Level7</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Science</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Level1</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Level2</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Level3</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Level4</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Level5</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Level6</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Level7</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a tabindex="-1" href="#">World Culture and Geography</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Level1</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Level2</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Level3</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Level4</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Level5</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Level6</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Level7</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Test</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Level1</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Level2</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Level3</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Level4</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Level5</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Level6</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Level7</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Inside</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Level1</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Level2</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Level3</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Level4</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Level5</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Level6</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Level7</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Edge</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Level1</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Level2</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Level3</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Level4</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Level5</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Level6</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Level7</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Our World</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Level1</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Level2</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Level3</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Level4</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Level5</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Level6</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Level7</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>  
</body>
```

I am making a dropdown menu with bootstrap.When the height of dropdown menu got higher than the screen size i tried to add scroll bar to it.Scroll bar is added correctly but problem is that now sub menu are not shown.they are hidden.